# Proving that a recursively defined sequence converges, Newton's method

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

> A sequence is defined recursively in the following manner:

$$ x_0 = 2, x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2 -3}{2x_n}, n = 0, 1, 2, ...$$

> Prove that the sequence converges. What does the sequence converge to?

Since the sequence is basically Newton's method for the function $f(x) = x^2 -3$, the sequence must converge to either $\sqrt3$ or -$\sqrt3$, but I'm not sure which one of them. I tried proving that the sequence converges using mathematical induction, but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: It surely converges to the positive square root—just run the process a time or two to convince yourself of that.

Answer (score 2):

write your term in the form $$x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{3}{x_n}\right)$$ and by $AM-GM$ we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{3}{x_n}\right)\geq \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: What do you mean by AM and GM? Btw, in the solution set they only used that $x_0 = 2$ and $f''(x) = 2 > 0$ to prove the sequence is convergent, but i didn't really get why that alone proves its convergent.

Comment: i mean the inequality $$\frac{a+b}{2}\geq \sqrt{ab}$$ for $$a,b\geq 0$$

Comment: How does this prove the sequence is actually approaching $\sqrt3$ though?

Answer (score 0):

Can you prove that $x_n>0$ implies $x_{n+1}>0$, to rule out negative limits for $x_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Note that if
$x_{n+1}
=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)
$
then
$x_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}
=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n-2\sqrt{a}+\frac{a}{x_n}\right)
=\frac1{2\sqrt{x_n}}(x_n-\sqrt a)^2
$
so that
once
$x_n$ is close enough to 
$\sqrt a$,
the sequence will converge.

Comment: I don't get why this proves the sequence converges. Also, how do we know $x_n$ will get close enough to $\sqrt a$ in the first place?